# variable changes when using if statement

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I've just started learning php an hour ago. I've made this code:

```
$x=2;  
$y=4;  
echo $x;  
echo $y;  

if($x=5) 
{    
    echo "$x";  
}  
else  
{  
    echo "test";  
}
```

I'm expecting the output: 24test

I'm getting the output: 245

x equals 2 in the beginning. Why is x then changing to 5 when the only thing I do is CHECKING whether x = 5?

I've searched the web and this site for an answer but couldn't find anything. Thanks in advance!

Tony

Comment: `if($x==5) ` will check whether $x is 5.

Comment: change this `if($x=5)` to this `if($x==5)`

Comment: have a quick look at [operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php) in php and the deferences between them

Comment: Thanks, that works!! Looking at the operators now...

Answer (score 0):

Note that = is use to assign value while == use to evaluate value within if statement so your code should be

```
if($x==5) {
```

Instead of

```
if($x=5) {
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your fast answers!

Comment: My dear when I start learning I faced the same problems so I know how it will be difficult to see your code not working for not a known reason at the early stage with the time everything will be easy